# Select columns when reading excel with multiindex header in Pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multi-index

I have an excel sheet that looks like this and I would like to read it as a multi-indexed Pandas Dataframe:

[image: table]

desired result:

```
       M1        M2     
site conc   LQ conc   LQ
C1 A    1  0.5   10  0.5
   B    2  0.6    5  0.6
   C  <LQ  1.0   14  1.0
C2 A  <LQ  1.1   12  1.1
   C    3  0.5   14  0.5
   D    1  0.5   11  0.5
```

The following code used to produce the desired result:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx", 
                   sheet_name="test",
                   header=[1,2],
                   index_col=[0,1],
                   usecols='A:B,D:G',
                   parse_dates = False,
                   )
```

But now (pandas version 0.25.1) it produces the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot specify usecols when specifying a multi-index header
```

Any ideas for a simple work-around?

To reproduce the excel table:

```
;;start;M1;;M2;;end;M1;;M2;
cam;site;bla;conc;LQ;conc;LQ;bla;conc;LQ;conc;LQ
C1;A;bla;1;0.5;10;0.5;bla;1;0.5;10;0.5
C1;B;bla;2;0.6;5;0.6;bla;2;0.6;5;0.6
C1;C;bla;<LQ;1;14;1;bla;<LQ;1;14;1
C2;A;bla;<LQ;1.1;12;1.1;bla;<LQ;1.1;12;1.1
C2;C;bla;3;0.5;14;0.5;bla;3;0.5;14;0.5
C2;D;bla;1;0.5;11;0.5;bla;1;0.5;11;0.5
```

Comment: Did you try to drop `usecols` from your argument list?

Comment: I enlarged my MWE to illustrate the need for 'usecols'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I had the same problem, you can't use `usecols` when `headers` is a multiple index

I solved the problem by doing this:

```
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx",
                   sheet_name="test",
                   header=2,
                   index_col=[0,1],
                   usecols='A:B,D:G',
                   parse_dates=False)
index = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx",
                      sheet_name="test",
                      header=None,
                      skiprows=1,
                      index_col=[0,1],
                      nrows=2,
                      usecols='A:B,D:G',
                      parse_dates=False)
index = index.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1)
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(index.values)
df
```