# Pandas dataframe with wrong level merging for multiIndex columns

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, multi-index

I have the following spreadsheet with two-row header as part of workbook.

[image]

```
Name Age Genre Monthly Annually Department        Region
P1   28  Female 1000   12000    I.T.              North
P2   25  Male   1100   13200    I.T.              South
P3   29  Female 1500   18000    Human Ressources  North
```

The goal is getting a data frame containing all data and one-level columns, where we get "./Genre", "Salary/Monthly", "Salary/Anually", "./Department", and so on. Even cells D1 and E1 being merged, Pandas looks at E1 such as C1 or F1 (empty content).
Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167366/select-columns-when-reading-excel-with-multiindex-header-in-pandas), I solved partially the issue adopting the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

minimal_df = test_df = pd.read_excel(io="multiIndex_columns.xlsx", sheet_name="sample", header=None, skiprows=2, nrows=3) 

minimal_index = pd.read_excel(io="multiIndex_columns.xlsx", sheet_name="sample", header=None, nrows=2)
```

If we see how `minimal_index` is presented, we find "Salary" at column 3 but not at 4.

```
      0    1      2        3        4           5       6
0   NaN  NaN    NaN   Salary      NaN         NaN     NaN
1  Name  Age  Genre  Monthly  Anually  Department  Region
```

Anyway, it's done assignment of column names to the data frame after NA values from auxiliary data frame have been filled.

```
minimal_index.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1, inplace=True)

minimal_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(minimal_index.values)
```

[image: Same data values color-highlighted but one-level columns with first three names associated to none and last four names to Salary]

```
nan/Name nan/Age nan/Genre Salary/Monthly Salary/Annually Salary/Department   Salary/Region
P1       28      Female    1000           12000           I.T.                North
P2       25      Male      1100           13200           I.T.                South
P3       29      Female    1500           18000           Human Ressources    North
```

Above, we check through PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4 the final result. However, columns Department and Region turn related to Salary also due to "ffill" method used by `fillna()`. On the other hand, I can assign nothing but keeping NaN values on first three columns because `fillna()` can't allow "value" and "method" arguments simultaneously.

Is there a way to solve both parts, avoiding file modifications by Excel? What solution, based on Pandas or another library, could recognize merging on input cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with pandas. I would use [openpyxl](/questions/tagged/openpyxl) to handle the [*merged*](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/merge.html) cells :

```
import openpyxl

ws = openpyxl.load_workbook("file.xlsx")["sample"]

TR, BR = 1, 2 # <-- top and bottom r-indices holding the header
SR = 3 # <-- the row indice where the table starts (excluding the header)

def get_val(x, sheet=ws):
    if isinstance(x, openpyxl.cell.cell.MergedCell):
        for r in sheet.merged_cells.ranges:
            if r.__contains__(x.coordinate):
                return r.start_cell.value 
    else:
        return x.value

header = [
    f"{get_val(c1)}/{get_val(c2)}" if get_val(c1) else f"./{c2.value}"
    for (c1,c2) in zip(ws[TR], ws[BR])
]

data = [row for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=SR, values_only=True)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

Output (*df*) :

| Info/Name | Info/Age | Info/Genre | ./Id | Salary/Monthly | Salary/Anually | ./Department | ./Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 28 | Female | id001 | 1000 | 12000 | I.T. | North |
| P2 | 25 | Male | id002 | 1100 | 13200 | I.T. | South |
| P3 | 29 | Female | id003 | 1500 | 18000 | Human Resources | North |

Used input (*file.xlsx*) :

[image]

Comment: **NB**: I added another *merged range* (`A1:C1`) to illustrate more the logic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like "Salary" is initially accross 2 merged EXCEL cells (D1, E1).

Un-merging those, then duplicating D1 to E1, should lead to a `minimal_index`as you expect it to be.

Comment: That's a good strategy, when we know we could do input modifications.