# Simple way to get data based on column subset from OpenPyXL Worksheet avoiding iterations

Tags: python, tuples, subset, openpyxl, worksheet

Imagine we want part of a dataset based on specific columns, which is on a worksheet by OpenPyXL.

```
ws = openpyxl.load_workbook("example_file.xlsx")["example_sheet"]
```

Is there a simple way to subset recurring to the tuples, such like the following ranges (Excel-like columns) are pretended?

```
ws = ws[ws['A,C,D,J:K,AI:AK']]
```

I know Pandas allows solving this, but the previous library is necessary to deal with [multi-level columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77022757/pandas-dataframe-with-wrong-level-merging-for-multiindex-columns) for instance. Even so, iterations seem to be the unique way but not clear enough. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a MultiCellRange object to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you are looking for is not possible. You need to iterate through the rows `for row in ws.iter_rows()` and then iterate through the cells `for cell in row` and filter the columns that you are looking for and extract the values.

Consider the following implementation, it has not been tested, improvise it for your need.

```py
for row in ws.iter_rows():
   for cell in row:
      if cell.column_letter in ['A,C,D,J,K,O,R']:
         value.append(cell.Value)
```

Comment: How `value` preserve the Worksheet structure so?

Comment: If you change the value, it is not going to be automatically reflect in the cell. If that is the requirement use pandas.